# FormData.delete is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, angular5, form-data

how to delete any **key** from FormData, bcoz **Internet Explorer** not support **FormData.delete**, here is my code, and i want to delete Formdata key,

```
this.PostRegistrationFormData = new FormData();
let localModel: any = _.clone(this.PostRegistrationModel);
this.PostRegistrationFormData.delete('profile_photo'); // FormData.delete not working in Internet Explorer.
```

so how to delete this?

Answer (score 2):

> **you have to delete key(profile_photo) before append in this.PostRegistrationFormData**.

```
this.PostRegistrationFormData = new FormData();
let localModel: any = _.clone(this.PostRegistrationModel);
delete localModel.profile_photo;
//this.PostRegistrationFormData.delete('profile_photo');
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you please clarify your answer?

Comment: before you append data into formData variable you can delete key from original variable then at the append time  it will not append in form data variable.